# Control access to Amazon DynamoDB entries using an entitlements table for federated users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to build an AWS architecture for a serverless application which stores files in a DynamoDB.

This database stores data which relates to a given perimeter. On the other hand I have data (M:N links) which link users of my application to some perimeters.

I want to make sure that my users (Authenticated on Amazon Cognito via a federated OIDC provider) only access to the data related to one of their perimeters.

- What is the best practice to implement this kind of access control logic with Amazon bricks ?
- Is it possible to accomplish such access control logic with IAM policies at the Dynamo DB level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a table

```
UserPerimeter
---
id (hash key)
userId (index - hash key)
perimeterId
```

And as part of your validation in your Lambda, you do a query on the index with the the user id from JWT/Cognito. This will check if he has access to the requested parameter. So basically protect your DB from your code (which is the only point of access).

You can achieve this from IAM, (check this [article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html)) but it adds too much complexity for my taste. This would be useful if the DB is used by multiple products/components/companies (which isn't a good practise anyway).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, which authorization mechanism does involve a Lambda ? Do I need to build a Lambda to access data in my case or is it a validation mechanism I can embed directly in DynamoDB ?

Comment: My mistake, I assumed you are using Lambda. I meant do the validation in your container/code

Comment: I want to have a serverless application with JavaScript requesting APIs through Amazon API Gateway or directly DynamoDB API to get data can I include such a validation mechanism somewhere ? Or is it possible to hide my DynamoDB behind a Lambda which performs such control ?

Comment: Yes, you need a Lambda layer which handles the data from DynamoDB